# How to use static objects in a class and how can we inherit the static object in other class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, static, webdriver

I am working in a selenium webdriver project.Here is my Framework shown in screenshot given below:
[image]

Here is the sample code , where I need to extend a static variable and a static object to another class.But when I try to extend the class , it shows some limitations in access modifiers.

```
package com.AFE_Framework;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
public class A 
{
   public static int dropdown_element_count;

   static WebElement afeTemplates;

   public static void Method_A (String A, String B)
   {
    WebElement createafeDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathvalue1));
        List<WebElement> afeTemplates = createafeDiv.findElements(By
                .xpath(xpathvalue2));

   }


}
==========================================================================
package com.AFE.TestCase

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.AFE_Framework.*;


public class B extends Class A 
{
  public static void Manage()   
    {
    **dropdown_element_count = afeTemplates.size() < --Here I am getting the error** 
    }

}
```

So can any one please help me to sort out this issue ?*

Comment: What does error say?

Comment: @PM77-1 The first error in that was , I cannot write the code as dropdown_element_count = afeTemplates.size(); because -"The method size() is undefined for the type WebElement,Change it to afeTemplates.getsize()". When I changed it to getsize(), it again showed error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dimension to int".

Answer (score 3):

This error is not related to static. Error is related to type mismatch.

Also I believe you are trying to count size in dropdown. I would suggest you to use Select class.

```
package com.AFE.TestCase

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.AFE_Framework.*;


public class B extends Class A 
{
  public static void Manage()   
    {
        Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(afeTemplates);


    List<WebElement> l = se.getOptions();

    dropdown_element_count = l.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: What was the type mismatch error occured? could you please explan it ?.And do we have the restriction for using WebElement class for inheriting to other class ?

Comment: What was the type mismatch error occured? could you please explan it ?
- You declared dropdown_element_count as int and 
afeTemplates.getSize() returns Dimension. So you can not store returning value to your variable.

And do we have the restriction for using WebElement class for inheriting to other class ?
- WebElement is predefined class, you can inherit it. But ineriting Webelement class from selenium does not sound logical.